# Single Column name splitting to multiple columns with data

Tags: pandas, numpy, csv

I am analyzing the inverter data from a power plant. There are more than 10 inverters and each inverter has 3 parameters that need to be analyzed. The parameters are Energy generated per interval, AC Power P_AC and DC Power P_DC. The inverters are numbered as 17.02 or 22.03 etc. The data is taken at a time step of 5minutes. After downloading the data in a csv file, there is only 1 column in the csv file. The column name contains numbers of all the inverter and their parameter names separated by a ';'. Also, the data at each time step is in 1 single cell separated by ';'. I want to analyse all the parameters of all the inverters and i want to make sure that each parameter of every inverter comes in a separate column. Can somebody help me to segregate this? Also, I want to ensure that columns are sorted in the increasing order of inverter numbering. I am attaching the the link to actual csv file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rp54DEarzFUGm2oU5Bfkl3karbUYYwcd/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12InL3N-ZMMODGWVUYn_8nTwPgAQtSBzq/view?usp=sharing

In the data frame above, you can see that every column has a project code -'SM10046 Akadyr Ext', then the inverter number 'INV 17.02' and then the name of parameter 'Energy generated per interval [kWh]' and lastly the code of parameter 'E_INT' . I want that the project code should be removed and only inverter number and parameter code should be present as a column name. Also, all the inverter should come in a serial order.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you have a multitude of columns, and from your description, you need to sort /analyze data from each plant ?

If you need permanent storage of data, I would use SQLite or similar, and convert each plant into a row with a key holding plant ID.

Like this:

```
2020-07-28 13:33:09;A1;A2;A3;B1;B2;B3
```

turned into something like this (now in a database, 5 fiels per record)

```
2020-07-28 13:33:09;A;A1;A2;A3
2020-07-28 13:33:09;B;A1;A2;A3
```

my goto-too for this would be a scripting language like AutoIT3, Perl or Python, which makes splitting lines and connecting to SQLite trivial.

If you just need real-time sorting/reporting etc, AWK is a perfect tool for this, since you can create sorted arrays very easily. (Perl/Python again of course alternatives as well).

It could be useful if you provide actual (trivial) example of what you expect output to be ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have modified the answer and added the image of the dataframe which i have created till now, but i am stuck with arranging the column in a serial order.

Comment: If you wish to order columns, there are some suggestions here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369732/how-to-sort-columns-based-on-the-first-line